# Explore tree structure in javascript in a For Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, tree

What options do I have to access the elements of a DOM tree in a For Loop ? And if it's too difficult can I convert it to an array ?

thanks,

Bruno

Comment: A list made of elements which can be lists too. Im' using Javascript and Dom to explore my bookmarks and a node can be sometimes a folder.

Comment: He is probably not a native English speaker. Nested and imbricated can both be valid translations from his language. @Bruno can you give us an example of such a list?

Comment: @Khez Good guess :-) Actually it's more a tree structure. The code above shows how this tree structure is created.

Comment: @Bruno you can use the DOM to traverse the list again, isn't that suitable ?

Comment: @Khez Actually I need it in a For structure and I don't know how to access its elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/CZA8x/).

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask. XML has a magnificent traversal system, this doesn't even begin to cut into the raw power of the DOM.

Also, be sure to check [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_element.asp), although it's not a [perfectly reliable source](http://w3fools.com/).

Comment: If you have questions, don't hesitate to spam with questions :)

Answer (score 1):

The DOM tree allows you to navigate down the levels using `.children` or `.childNodes()`.

`.children()` provides an array of DOM elements below the current one, and `.childNodes()` provides all nodes, including text nodes.

You can also use `getElementById()` to get a specific node (much quicker than any array search could ever be), and `getElementsByTagName()` to get all elements of a particular type.

I definitely wouldn't recommend converting it to an array -- the DOM tree as it stands is much more flexible than any array.

If you need more flexibility, you could try JQuery, which gives you even more flexibility for searching the DOM by adding complex CSS-style selector queries to the mix. (modern browsers also provide this natively with the `getElementsBySelector()` method, but this isn't available in all browsers, so you're better off using JQuery or similar for this for the time being)